# Is there a way to prevent a select menu from closing if the value change dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to be able to make an ajax request when a user opens a select menu "before the menu opens".

The ajax request will tell me what option should be enabled or disabled.

My first thought I was to bind an click event. In other words, on the `click` event make ajax call. The problem with using the `click` event is that I need to change the value dynamically when the ajax request finish to make sure the default value is selected after ajax completes.

The problem that I am running into is that every time the user clicks on the menu, the options come up and it immediately closes "unless the user hold down the mouse".

What event can I use to be able to make my ajax request, enable/disable options but keep the menu open instead of closing it?

Also, after the user clicks on the menu it will always rest to the value "0" because after the user clicks on the option it fires the event all over again.

Here is what I have done

```
$(function (e) {

    $('#MasterWrapUps').on('click', function (e) {

        var menu = $(this);

        var status = "noattempt";

        //enable only the noattempt dispos by default
        attrWrapUpMenu(menu, status);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/getstatus",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data) {

                //reselect the selected option to the default
                menu.val('0');

                if ( data && ! $.isEmptyObject(data) ) {
                    status = data.status;
                }

                attrWrapUpMenu(menu, status);

            }
        });

    });

    function attrWrapUpMenu(menu, status)
    {
        menu.find('option').each(function (index, element) {

            var option = $(element);

            if (option.val() != '0' ) {

                if (customIsAllowed(status, option)) {
                    option.attr("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    option.attr("disabled", true);
                }

            }

        });
    }

    function customIsAllowed(status, option)
    {
        var status = status.toLowerCase();

        var group = option.attr('data-group');

        if (group && group.toLowerCase().indexOf(status) > -1) {
             return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5L1ofuj/1/) using Chrome 48 and it works fine... what is the issue again?

Comment: the issue once again after the ajax request finishes the menu close and the value will go back to val(0). I only want that behavior when the menu open not when it is clicked on

Comment: I added some delay to the AJAX request [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m5L1ofuj/2/) and it still doesn't close the menu at all to me. Have you tried different browsers?. You can add my JSFiddle to your question if you want. It could be useful for someone else trying to help.

Comment: It closed in IE8 in compatibility mode.  also I added the default option to your code please have a look https://jsfiddle.net/m5L1ofuj/4/

Comment: This looks like a browser dependant problem. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't on IE and Edge. Here is the latest [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5L1ofuj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$('#MasterWrapUps').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```